# Please explain this statement of mips?

Tags: mips

[image]

Can anyone explain this to me?

The first line i don't get. How does the first line make the content in $s3 *4?
i know it shifts it to the left how does shifting $s3 by 2 to the left make it 4 times bigger?

Comment: I’m sorry but you aren’t using this site properly. Please check out the documentation in the help center. Also, why do you think it’s ok to leave “enter image description here” as it is? There’s just simply no effort put in to your question.

Comment: What part do you not understand? The code is well commented and follows the pseudocode below it.

Comment: The first line i don't get. How does the first line make the content in $s3    *4?

Answer (score 1):

Consider decimals. E.g. you shift 123<sub>10</sub> 2 positions left. You get two zeroes on the right: 12300<sub>10</sub>. 1 position is equivalent to 10<sub>10</sub>. 2 positions are equivalent to 100<sub>10</sub>.

Same with binary numbers. Shift 101<sub>2</sub> 2 positions left. You get two zeroes on the right: 10100<sub>2</sub>. 1 position is equivalent to 10<sub>2</sub>, which is 2<sub>10</sub>. 2 positions are equivalent to 100<sub>2</sub>, which is 4<sub>10</sub>.

Comment: i get it. 101(base 2) = 5 and 10100(base 2) = 20. This 4 times the value

Comment: every time you move left, you increase multiple in 2 same as in the decimal number every decimal place you move you increase by 10